# Improving build time of a cross platform Electron app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an existing electron project, To test the application on multiple OSs(Mac, Windows, Linux) we are building the app using electron-builder.
Currently, the build process takes around 15-20 mins.

I'm using a mac machine and already have set up Microsoft Windows and Linux VM on Azure so I don't have to keep switching physical machines also the project has hot-reload setup.

Here is the config.json used to build:

```
{
      "appId": "myApp",
      "icon": "resources/icon",
      "productName": "myProduct",
      "extraMetadata": {
        "name": "myApp"
      },
  "mac": {
    "extendInfo": {},
    "extraFiles": [
      "PlugIns/"
    ]
  },
  "dmg": {
    "contents": [
      {
        "x": 110,
        "y": 150
      },
      {
        "x": 240,
        "y": 150,
        "type": "link",
        "path": "/Applications"
      }
    ]
  },
  "linux": {
    "category": "Development",
    "target": [
      "AppImage",
      "deb"
    ]
  },
  "win": {
    "target": [
      "nsis",
      "msi"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "resources/fileIcons",
        "to": "fileIcons"
      }
    ]
  },
  "nsis": {
    "allowElevation": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
    "createDesktopShortcut": true,
    "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
    "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
    "oneClick": false,
    "perMachine": true,
    "uninstallDisplayName": "${productName}"
  },
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources/app",
    "output": "release/my-app"
  },
  "publish": {
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": Some-s3-url
  }
}
```

The motive is to reduce the build time by optimizing the build process.

Comment: @somesh I hope the edit made the question more objective and fact-based, request to reopen